# How to sort a list of dictionaries of dictionaries by value

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a `list` of `dict`s of `dict`s like this:

```
mydic = [{'name':'a', 'loc':{'locname':'z'}, 'id':{'value':'1'}},{'name':'b', 'loc':{'locname':'o'}, 'id':{'value':'2'}}]
```

How do I sort it by `locname`? I should get this:

```
mydic_sorted = [{'name':'b', 'loc':{'locname':'o'}, 'id':{'value':'2'}}, {'name':'a', 'loc':{'locname':'z'}, 'id':{'value':'1'}}]
```

Comment: 4 upvotes. Seriously?

Comment: The biggest question is, how can one submit a question like this without noticing all the duplicates in the list that essentially have the title identical to the title of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can by using a `lambda` function as a `key` argument to the function

```
>>> mydic = [{'name':'a', 'loc':{'locname':'z'}, 'id':{'value':'1'}},{'name':'b', 'loc':{'locname':'o'}, 'id':{'value':'2'}}]
>>> sorted(mydic,key = lambda x:x['loc']['locname'])
[{'loc': {'locname': 'o'}, 'name': 'b', 'id': {'value': '2'}}, {'loc': {'locname': 'z'}, 'name': 'a', 'id': {'value': '1'}}]
```

**Ref:** The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

> `sorted(iterable[, cmp[, key[, reverse]]])`
>
> `key` specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element: `key=str.lower`. The default value is `None` (compare the elements directly).

Comment: thnx for your quick answer :)